# Integrate a Spreadshop site using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a website using React, and I want to integrate a shop from spreadshop.com / spreadshirt.com, to my React website.
Spreadshop.com gives quite good instructions on how to use script-tags to integrate their shop to an html-site ([instructions can be found here](https://help.spreadshop.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360010529039-Website-Integration-with-JavaScript)).

I am not an experienced programmer, and I'm a little confused about how scripts work with React and especially about where I should put the spread_shop_config, which the Spreadshop instructions tells me to have available in window Scope. I have tried to use a useScript-hook, which I found [here](https://gist.github.com/gragland/929e42759c0051ff596bc961fb13cd93). But it doesn't seem to work.
Below is my implementation attempt so far.
What am I doing wrong? How can I integrate the Spreadshirt shop to my React website?

```
import React from 'react';
import useScript from './Hooks/useScript';

function Shop() {

  const [loaded, error] = useScript('https://shop.spreadshirt.no/shopfiles/shopclient/shopclient.nocache.js');
 
  var spread_shop_config = {
      shopName: 'awesome-merch-shop',
      locale: 'US',
      prefix: 'https://shop.spreadshirt.com',
      baseId: 'shop'
  }

  return (
    <div className="shopBody">
      {loaded && !error && (
        <div id="shop">
          <div>
            <i id="spinner" className="fa fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true"/>
            <p>Loading The Shop...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Shop;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer myself here, since I figured a better way and which actually works (better) for all scripts even if you need to add multiple different scripts to a page/component.
(Now I'm actually confused why we need a useScript-hook at all).

Inside the react component that needs to use the script, it seems better to use javascript to create a script-element and then append it to the document.body.

So in example, to add the Spreadshop.com script inside the Shop-component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Shop.css';

function Shop() {

  var js = document.createElement("script");
  js.type = "text/javascript";
  js.src = "https://shop.spreadshirt.no/shopfiles/shopclient/shopclient.nocache.js";
  document.body.appendChild(js);

  return (
    <div className="shopBody">
      <div id="shop">
        <i id="spinner" className="fa fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true"/>
        <p>Loading The Shop...</p>
      </div>
   </div>
  );
}

export default Shop;
```

And the Spreadshop configurations variable I just add normally with script tags inside the index.html in the publics folder.

```
<script>
  var spread_shop_config = {
    shopName: 'awesome-merch-shop',
    locale: 'US',
    prefix: 'https://shop.spreadshirt.com',
    baseId: 'shop'
  }
</script>
```

By doing it this way, the Spreadshop script won't give an error message when loading every component, because the script is only appended when that component loads.
And also, since the script is loaded whenever that component is loaded, it will work even if you refresh the page, while if the script was only in the index.html then the index.html would have to be loaded for the script to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Include the javascript and Spreadshirt config in your high-level index.js file. For most it's something like `/public/index.html` (the same folder you have your manifest.json, robots.txt, etc) along with my google fonts and bootstrap include before `</html>`

For my implementation I added

```
  <script>
    var spread_shop_config = {
        shopName: 'YourShopNameHere',
        locale: 'us_US',
        prefix: 'https://shop.spreadshirt.com',
        baseId: 'myShop'
    };
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://shop.spreadshirt.com/shopfiles/shopclient/shopclient.nocache.js"></script>
```

And then in the React component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Shop.css';

type Props = {
  testProp: string
};

export const Shop = ({ testProp }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div id="Shop-Component">
         <div id="myShop">
             <div>is loading text here...</div>
         </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default(Shop);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it to work! :D
However I still have two problems:
1) The shop only renders when I refresh the page exactly on the shop-page. If I navigate to another page and then back to the shop, then it doesn't render. It only shows the <div>is loading text here...</div>.
2) A big red <div>-element now displays at the bottom of every other page, where it says: "Could not embed your SpreadShop!
Please add a container with the id 'YourShopNameHere' to your HTML file.
More information can be found at
https://help.spreadshop.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010529039".

Comment: Do you know how to solve those two problems?
Thank you so much for your help anyways! :)